# pgfplots: labels and width issues in non-boxed 3d plot with oblique projection

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

### Update april 2013

The bug has been fixed with `pgfplots` version 1.8 (requires `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}`).

---

When I try to add the axes labels to this code, I get a `division by zero` error. I think the error is responsive to the choice of the unit vectors directions (see after).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} % *EDIT*: this improves scale uniformly.

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,
             % *EDIT*: this here respects your choice of unit vectors.
             %         scale uniformly computes one common scaling factor
             %         and chooses limits such that the image fulfills the 
             %         prescribed width/height as best as possible.
             x={(-0.3535cm,-0.3535cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)},
             scale mode=scale uniformly,
             xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
            ]

\addplot3 coordinates {(0,0,0) (0.5,-0.5,0.8)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now look at this code with a different choice of unit vectors. The axes labels are drawn (I get no error), but far away from their axis and overlapped. Moreover, the actual width is about 5 cm and not 10 cm as it should be (`scale only axis` won't help here).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} % *EDIT*: this improves scale uniformly.

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=10cm,
             axis lines=center,
             xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1, zmin=0, zmax=1,      
             % *EDIT*: this here respects your choice of unit vectors.
             %         scale uniformly computes one common scaling factor
             %         and chooses limits such that the image fulfills the 
             %         prescribed width/height as best as possible.
             x={(0.94cm,-0.34cm)}, y={(0.766cm,0.643cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)},
             scale mode=scale uniformly,
             xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
            ]

\addplot3 coordinates {(0,0,0) (0.5,-0.5,0.8)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting.. The divide by 0 must be coming from some calculation that is begin done to determine where the axis labels are to be placed. The only solution I can come up is not very ideal, and that is to manually place the axis labels: `\node  at (axis cs: 0.85,0,0)  {$x$};
\node  at (axis cs: 0,0.30,0) {$y$};
\node  at (axis cs: 0,0,0.85) {$z$};`.

Comment: About the width issue: When you provide the unit vectors, the `width` and `height` keys have no effect, because the dimensions of the plot are already determined by the axis ranges and the unit vectors.

Comment: @Jake, this isn't totally true. If you double the width, you'll see that the actual width doubles too, even if its dimension is wrong.

Comment: @Luigi: Ah yes, you're right. Hm, another weird behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is indeed strange behaviour regarding the placement of the labels. You might want to [file a bug report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=224188&atid=1060656) for this. In the meantime, you can work around this by redefining the relevant label styles using something like

```
every axis x label/.style={
    at={(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0,0)},
    xshift=-1em                 
},
every axis y label/.style={
    at={(axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax},0)},
    yshift=2ex,             
},
every axis z label/.style={
    at={(axis cs:0,0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax})},
    xshift=1em             
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,
             x={(-0.3535cm,-0.3535cm)}, y={(1cm,0.0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)},
             scale mode=scale uniformly,
             xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
    every axis x label/.style={
        at={(axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0,0)},
        xshift=-1em                 
    },
    every axis y label/.style={
        at={(axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax},0)},
        yshift=2ex,             
    },
    every axis z label/.style={
        at={(axis cs:0,0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax})},
        xshift=1em             
    }
]
\addplot3 coordinates {(0,0,0) (0.5,-0.5,0.8)};
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice workaround! I'll wait for Christian's feedback, otherwise I'll file the bug report. Thank you.

Comment: That is a known bug ...