# Uniform appearance of tick marks in 3d pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

In the default configuration the tick marks in a 3d plot from `pgfplots` are looking nicely when using a box but in my opinion not really uniform when the axis lines are in the center. Is there any option to show uniform crosses, for example 3 lines in all directions at each minor tick mark? Here I have crosses along one axis and only lines along both other axes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={tick style={line width=0.7pt}}}

\pgfplotstableread{
a b
-0.1 0.2
0.1 0.5
}\testdata

\begin{axis}[axis lines=center, ymin=-0.22,ymax=0.22,   ]
    \addplot3 [color=blue,] table[x expr=0,y=a,z=b] {\testdata};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this answer to a different question, the crosses look the same in all axis http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84450/1871, I don't know why but you can explore that example to figure it out. (and let us know)

Comment: @alfC: Thanks for the hint. It seems that the crosses along the x-axis are drawn in a plane that is parallel to the yz-plane. For some strange reason the crosses along the y-axis are here also drawn in the yz-plane and therefore partially disappear. I have no idea why that is the case or how to change it.

Comment: Maybe `pgfplots` is trying to be smart and not produce crosses with projected shallow angles (will display basically as blob in many cases). Try a different `view` angle and see if the problem persists. Also try much thinner lines for the axis and ticks.

Comment: I guessed wrong. I think `pgfplots` is simply treating the x, and y axis differently than the z-axis.

Comment: It is very strange if I put the option `y dir=reverse` (just to try something, I see the full crosses in all directions).

Comment: That is a bug in pgfplots, I accept it as bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bug in `pgfplots`, I accept it as bug report.

I plan to fix it in the next stable release (the one after `pgfplots` 1.10).

Comment: Just a suggestion: depending and the angle at which the lines in the crosses meet and the thickness of the lines, sometimes it may not be a good idea to actually display the two lines of the cross.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, alfC, you are right. I noted this as feature request and will think about a suitable place to chick this condition. The bug as such is fixed now.